# in_array can find a town name fetched from mysql row to check inside town names array

Tags: php, mysql

I validate two postcodes then run two mysql query to get the postal city of each postcode
then the postal city will be compared with two arrays to see if the postal city is an inner london district or not or it is an outter london district.
my code run without any error but 
when put inside in_array can not set the flag to 1 or to 0.
does not output anything.  I know i should switch to mysqli or pdo.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
    $innerlondon = array('Bromley', 'Croydon', 'Dartford', 'East London', 'City of London', 'Enfield', 'Harrow', 'Ilford', 'Kingston-upon-Thames', 'North London', 'North West London', 'Romford', 'South East London', 'Sutton', 'South West London', 'Twickenham', 'Southall', 'West End', 'West Central');


    $outterlondon = array('Aberdeen', 'Bath', 'Belfast', 'Birmingham', 'Blackburn', 'Blackpool', 'Bolton', 'Bournemouth', 'Bradford', 'Brighton', 'Bristol', 'Cambridge', 'Canterbury', 'Cardiff', 'Carlisle', 'Chelmsford', 'Chester', 'Colchester', 'Coventry', 'Crewe', 'Darlington', 'Derby', 'Doncaster', 'Dorchester', 'Dudley', 'Dumfries', 'Dundee', 'Durham', 'Exeter', 'Falkirk', 'Galashiels', 'Glasgow', 'Gloucester', 'Guernsey', 'Guildford', 'Halifax', 'Harrogate', 'Hebrides', 'Hemel Hempstead', 'Hereford', 'Huddersfield', 'Hull', 'Ipswich', 'Isle Of Man', 'Jersey', 'Kilmarnock', 'Kirkcaldy', 'Kirkwall', 'Lancaster', 'Leeds', 'Leicester', 'Lerwick', 'Lincoln', 'Liverpool', 'Llandrindod', 'Llandudno', 'lnverness', 'Luton', 'Manchester', 'Medway', 'Milton Keynes', 'Motherwell', 'Newcastle', 'Newport', 'Northampton', 'Norwich', 'Nottingham', 'Oldham', 'Oxford', 'Paisley', 'Perth', 'Peterborough',    'Plymouth', 'Portsmouth', 'Preston', 'Reading', 'Redhill', 'Salisbury', 'Sheffield', 'Shrewsbury', 'Slough', 'Southampton', 'Southend-on-Sea', 'St Albans', 'Stevenage', 'Stockport', 'Stoke-on-Trent', 'Sunderland', 'Swansea', 'Swindon', 'Taunton', 'Teesside', 'Telford', 'Tonbridge', 'Torquay', 'Truro', 'Wakefield', 'Walsall', 'Warrington', 'Watford', 'Wigan', 'Wolverhampton', 'Worcester', 'York');



$sql = "SELECT `town` FROM `ukpostcodes` WHERE `postcode`='$postcode1' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $postal_town1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

    if(in_array($postal_town1, $innerlondon ))
    {
        echo "It is an inner London District = ";   
        echo $town1=$postal_town1['town'];
        echo $inlondon=1; //set flag to 1
    }
    else
    {
        echo $inlondon=0; //set flag to 0
    }

    $sql = "SELECT `town` FROM `ukpostcodes` WHERE `postcode`='$postcode2' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $postal_town2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 

    if(in_array($postal_town2, $outterlondon ))
    {
        echo "&nbsp;It is an outter London District = ";    
        echo $town2=$postal_town2['town'];  
        echo $outlondon=1; //set flag to 1
    }
    else
    {
        echo $outlondon=0; //set flag to 0
    }
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()` returns an array, so you need to do `if(in_array($postal_town1['town'], $innerlondon ))` and `if(in_array($postal_town2['town'], $innerlondon ))`

Comment: Sean thank you for replying, not working still outputs 0 0

Comment: I solved the issue by using the trim() function.